# Anyway to speed up a WorkSheetFunction.Clean VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below Excel VB code and it works well the issue it however it runs rather slowly and wondering if there is anyway to speed up the process.
CODE:

```
Sub cleanSheet()

Dim r As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each r In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(200, 12))
    r = WorksheetFunction.Clean(r)
Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So basically I have data in columns A:L that need need to be cleaned.  I was hoping for something maybe that can just take the entire range for example A1:L200 and clean in one go than have to loop through each cell.

Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will transfer the *Range* to a **VBA** *Array*
Then cleanup the array and then transfer back to the range:

```
Sub cleanup()
    Dim ary As Range
    Set ary = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(200, 12))
    bry = ary.Value
    For i = 1 To 200
        For j = 1 To 12
            bry(i, j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(bry(i, j))
        Next j
    Next i
    ary = bry
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a million Gary's Student and thanks for the explaination